# How can i compare 3 Strings and then make it in alphabetical order? (java)

Tags: java

How can I compare 3 Strings and then make it in alphabetical order? So if the arguments were “Berry”, “alex”, “cory” you would return one string with “alex, Berry, cory”. (java)
I used compare to and I found the first letter but for some reason (something that I did wrong) is nor working

My program how can I fix it?

```
   public String CW4J( String A, String B, String C )
{ 
  /// format will be like this  A+","+B+","+C
  String TEMP;
  String firstLetter  = "";
  String secondletter  = "";
  String thirdletter  = "";
  firstLetter = String.valueOf(A.charAt(0));
  secondletter = String.valueOf(B.charAt(0));
  thirdletter = String.valueOf(C.charAt(0));
  
  for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
  int compare = firstLetter.compareTo(secondletter);  
  if (compare < 0) {  
    TEMP = B;
    B = A;
    A = TEMP;
  } else if (compare > 0) {
    TEMP = A;
    A = B;
    B = TEMP;
  }
  
  compare = thirdletter.compareTo(secondletter);  
  if (compare < 0) {  
     TEMP = B;
    B = C;
    C = TEMP;
  } else if (compare > 0) {
    TEMP = C;
    C = B;
    B = TEMP;
  }
  
   compare = firstLetter.compareTo(thirdletter);  
  if (compare < 0) {  
    TEMP = C;
    C = A;
    A = TEMP;
  } else if (compare > 0) {
    TEMP = A;
    A = C;
    C = TEMP;
  }}
  return A+","+B+","+C;
}
```

Comment: Look at [this table](http://www.asciitable.com/). Lowercase letters all come after uppercase letters with their values. You will have to compare only lower or only upper to make them in order. Or, find a way to compare case-insensitively.

Comment: `char` type in Java is outmoded, unable to represent even half of the characters in Unicode.

Comment: If you doing homework assignment or academic exercise, you should say so. That affects the kinds of answers you receive.

Answer (score 4):

Much better to:

- add each string to a List
- sort the list
- join the strings together

That will work for more than 3 strings without an explosion of comparisons.

Please try to implement it that way, and update your question with any issues you have.

Comment: I have to do it with if statement short won't help me here thanks for the advice! I have to place the items in the String in the correct order so parameters “B”,”C”,”A” becomes “A,B,C”. That's what I tried to do in my program above

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `List<String> list`  of strings and then sort it as `Collections.sort(list, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)`. Finally,  [`list#toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString--) will give you the string you are looking for.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of("Berry", "alex", "cory"));
        Collections.sort(list, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        String result = list.toString();
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[alex, Berry, cory]
```

Comment: I have to do it with if statement and then return it thanks for the advice! I have to place the items in the String in the correct order so parameters “B”,” C”,” A” becomes “A, B, C”. That's what I tried to do in my program above but I did sth wrong probably that I can't see

Comment: @BloodyAssault - I could not understand if it solved your problem or you need any further help.

Comment: No, it didn't. Basically what I need is put the strings in growing alphabetical orders and returns a string with all of them (in order) separated by commas 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   String temp, allNames = "";
   String []names = {"Berry","alex","cory"};
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
   {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 3; j++) 
        {
            if (names[i].compareToIgnoreCase(names[j])>0) 
            {
               temp = names[i];
               names[i] = names[j];
               names[j] = temp;
            }
        }
      allNames += names[i] + ",";
   }
   System.out.print("Names : " + allNames);
```